# Why did sinkholes emerge in Pakistan?

Tags: crust

[image]

[Here is a video](https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2018/07/03/video-huge-sinkhole-emerges-on-lahores-mall-road-after-heavy-rain/).

Why did the sinkhole emerge in Pakistan? Is this because of the heavy exploitation of groundwater?

What could be the solution?

**Reference**

- [In pictures: Chaos as rain continues to lash Lahore](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1748641/1-pictures-chaos-rain-continues-lash-lahore/)
- [NDMA sends out monsoon alert, expects more urban flooding in Lahore, Rawalpindi](https://www.dawn.com/news/1417680)
- [Sinkhole emerges near GPO on Mall Road](https://dunyanews.tv/en/Pakistan/446353-Sinkhole-emerges-near-GPO-Mall-Road--)
- [Those responsible for Lahore sinkhole will be punished: Interim transport minister](https://www.geo.tv/latest/201794-lahore-crack)

Comment: Sinkholes usually form when water erodes material which over time creates a cavity. When the size of the cavity is too large to crown collapses, forming a subsidence hole of the surface. Some sinkholes are created when water pipes leak significant amounts of water over time. Other sinkholes form because the ground they form in are easily dissolved by water, particularly acidic water, such as limestone. Most of us at this site are not familiar with the sinkhole situation in Pakistan, or the geology of the sinkhole locations. Could you please provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

I was about to ask a question whether this should be classified as a sinkhole or not. This is because this so-called 'sinkhole' is not entirely because of a natural process. It seems that it was the underground GPO Station (or the tunnel) of [Orange Line Metro Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Line_(Lahore_Metro)) Station that collapsed.

I can't seem to find an article that specifically mentions this. One [news article](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1748529/1-least-six-dead-rain-related-incidents-lahore/) I found isn't exactly very clear about it, but suggests this to be the case.

I think you can blame the 'sinkhole' (or collapse) or the failure of the underground structure. One of your source's title "Those responsible for Lahore sinkhole will be punished" also seems to suggest that it has only man-made causes, and not natural.

Further sources:
[Punjab Mass Transit Authority - Orange Line Metro](https://pma.punjab.gov.pk/olmts)

P.S. I live here. :)